# Updating a plot after show

Tags: matplotlib, plot

Say I have created a plot and then I show it

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
lt.plot(mat0[21:27,1],mat0[21:27,4],marker='s', label = "21")
lt.plot(mat0[21:27,1],mat0[21:27,3],marker='s', label = "23")
plt.plot(mat0[21:27,1],mat0[21:27,2],marker='s', label = "28")
pl.show()
```

I then realize that I have missed some lines to plot, how can I update the graph without going through all the process of plotting every single line again?

Comment: Are you using an ipython terminal? If so, you can set your backend to e.g. Qt4Agg, which will allow you to continue adding to a plot when it is shown.

Comment: set the `mpl` session to interactive using `plt.ion()` before you start plotting, and then you can keep adding to the plot without needing to `plt.show()`

Comment: @tom @_Angus Williams This looks like an answer to me